# Очень долгая загрузка данных

Tags: php, yii2, apache, nginx, debian

У меня есть сайт на ***yii2***. Там есть дерево категорий, которое раскрывается. При раскрытии отправляется ***ajax*** запрос, который подгружает подкатегории. Проблема в том, что подгрузка идет очень долго, минуты 2-3, хотя дебагер показывает меньше 100ms. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Система - Debian, apache+nginx работают в связке, база - mysql

P.S. Запросы тоже исполняются быстро, как минимум так пишет дебагер. Так же прикладываю скрин - [скрин](http://joxi.ru/zANWZ18FBjNkMr)

Comment: тут проблема именно в настройках сервера, а не запросах. Сами ajax запросы медленно доходят

Comment: А как вы определили что подгрузка происходит 2-3 минуты? Какое визуально регистрируемое событие говорило об окончании подгрузки?

Comment: Лучше смотрите в инспекторе, а не консольке Yii. Там расписанно больше по таймингам. Сколько до TTFB? Сколько байт приходит в ответе? Ну и остальные параметры

Comment: дебагер на скрине показывает сколько времени тратится на отправку ajax запроса. То что он показывает 100ms - это когда запрос уже дошел и это считается чисто обработка сервера. Проблема в настройках сервера

Comment: @PHPLego, происходить отображение данных. По поводу настроек сервера - в какую сторону копать?